# Perspective projection matrix -clip space co ordinates

Tags: opengl

I have have been reading [The Matrix has You](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20The%20Matrix%20Has%20You.html) trying to understand the perpective matrix.

This tutorial uses frustum scale fator `S` to define the perspective matrix as below .

```
Xclip = S * Xcamera
Yclip = S * Ycamera
```

But there are other tutorials like [OpenGL Projection Matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) which define the

```
xclip = 2 * n / (r-l)
yclip = 2 * n / (t-b)
```

Could some one please help me understand if they are same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `S=2n/(r-l)` or `S=2n/(t-b)` respectively, you end up with the same equations (don't forget the multiplication with `x_camera` and `y_camera` in the second case). In the first equations, the scale factor is just precalculated from other constants. Note that the scale factor is usually different for x and y, because the view frustum's base is not a square.

Comment: But S is calculated differently in the tutorial . Its FOV* pi/180 . FOV = field of view angle in degrees . Will this give the same value as the second equations ?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the accurate formula (reference?). This seems unreasonable in any way. Usually, this would be something like `1/tan(fov/2)`. Then we know that `2 * n * tan(fov/2) = t - b`. Re-arranging this equation yields `S = 2 * n / (t - b) = 1 / tan(fov/2)`

Comment: This is the reference http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut06%20Translation.html The method name is CalcFrustumScale()

Comment: I am confused since I don't see this formula any where else . But I see the formula 2 * n / (t - b) = 1 / tan(fov/2) in almost all the other tutorias

Comment: `CalcFrustumScale()` returns `1 / tan(fov/2)`. The formula `tan(fov/2) = (t - b) / 2 / n` is basically the pure definition of the tangens applied to the frustum looked at from above (triangle positioned at eye).